# Evaluating equality of sorted pandas dataframes does not behave as expected

Tags: python, pandas, equality

I would like to compare two `pd.dataframes` for equality:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame([['between', 1.5], ['between', 2], 
                    ['between', 2.0], ['within', 2.0]], 
                   columns=['Group', 'Distance'])

bar = pd.DataFrame([['between', 2], ['between', 1.5], 
                    ['within', 2.0], ['between', 2.0]], 
                   columns=['Group', 'Distance'])
```

As far as I am concerned these two dataframes are identical, however I realize pandas does not agree because they are not in the same order. My thought was that I could sort and then reindex

```
foo = foo.sort_values('Distance').reset_index(drop=True)
bar = bar.sort_values('Distance').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Pandas sort gives different results because of the initial ordering of the dataframes. And in fact they don't evaluate as being equivalent:

```
foo.equals(bar)
False
```

I could first sort on `Group` and then on `Distance` and this would return `True`, however in dealing with larger dataframes I'm concerned about having to explicitly define sorting rules each time. Is there a better way of comparing two differently ordered dataframes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you can make them evaluate to `True`:

```
foo.sort_values(foo.columns.values.tolist()).reset_index(drop=True).equals(bar.sort_values(foo.columns.values.tolist()).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Or

```
foo = foo.sort_values(foo.columns.values.tolist()).reset_index(drop=True)
bar = bar.sort_values(foo.columns.values.tolist()).reset_index(drop=True)
foo.equals(bar)
True
```

Comment: Alternative solution: `(foo.sort_values(['Group', 'Distance']).values == bar.sort_values(['Group', 'Distance']).values).all()`